# In-app purchase Error while retrieving information from server [DF-AA-20] - android

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

I am trying to enable in app billing. I've created In-app-products on my google play console and got my license key. When I try to purchase product I get this image error.

[in-app purchase error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edy1f.png)

Here is the code I use to create BillingProcessor.

```
    bp = new BillingProcessor(getApplicationContext(), 
 getString(R.string.google_licence_key), this);
    bp.initialize(); // binds
    boolean isAvailable = BillingProcessor.isIabServiceAvailable(this);
    if (!isAvailable) {
        // continue
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YESSSSSSSSs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    btn_bill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CLICKED", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // bp.purchase(BillingActivity.this,android.test.purchased");
            bp.subscribe(BillingActivity.this, "xyz"); //, "DEVELOPER PAYLOAD HERE"
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The possibility of error,

- Need to upload app on the app store for the beta, alpha or live version at least once.
- Uploaded app on play store app version and testing app version should be same,
- Please verify created product id and requesting product id same or not,
- Also finally verify product are active or Inactive, If Inactive then active it.

Comment: okay sure, I will upload a testing version on  play-store hope it will works